# CRS for Baghdad, Iraq

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, iraq

whenever i try to add a buffer to a certain layer it does that in degrees , i realized that i need to change the CRS but there are a ton of them
what do i need to know to choose the correct CRS for that layer to change it into meters?

The area that I am working on is Baghdad in Iraq.

Comment: they are seperated into geographic and projected coodinate systems . you will nedd one from the projected type. for seach look at http://epsg.io/ to find one which can be applied in your area of interest

Comment: The projected coordinate system to use will be one appropriate for where in the world your data is located.  That is information that you should [edit] into your question.

Comment: What is the CRS of the layer you're buffering?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an appropriate [UTM zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) for your region.  UTM has a linear measurement unit in meters which will work with QChainage (as per your other question).  Alternatively, if their is a national mapping agency for your region that has specified a CRS (e.g. for the UK it would be OSGB), use that (so long as it has meters as the unit of measurement).

You can use [this facility](http://www.epsg-registry.org/) to search for potential CRS for a given area (draw your area on the map and when you close the popup the coordinates are entered in the form for you - then click search).  You will get a lot of answers but it can help narrow the field and each suggestion has a link to its documentation.

And/OR refine your question to stae your geographic area of interest and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: I was referring to the way the UTM grid divides up the world into 6 degree portions - but since I didn't go into detail that was confusing so I've removed the comment - it's not really relevant anyway.